# BZip2 input stream bad block header in c#

Tags: c#

I have made a method for working with bzip2 files. My goal is decompressing bzip2 files, but I got this error.

> BZip2 input stream bad block header

I searched for this error, but I couldn't find any solution for that. Also, I have used SharpZipLib library.

```
public void Bzip2Files()
{
    try
    {
        string destFolder = @"C:\Users\ABC\Desktop\term\a.bz2";
        string decompressedFileName = @"C:\Users\ABC\Desktop\term\bzip2\decompressed.txt";
        var zip = new BZip2InputStream(System.IO.File.OpenRead(destFolder));
        var filestream = new FileStream(destFolder, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        using (FileStream decompressedStream = File.Create(decompressedFileName))
        {
            try
            {
                BZip2.Decompress(filestream, decompressedStream, true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add an example of a.bz2 file

Comment: I've used your code and everything works for me. Could you please provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue. I checked Mime Type of bzip2 file, and I got it wasn't bzip2, but it was gzipped file. To check mime type of files, you can use this website
https://filext.com/